# Angular2: Double slash in url

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, router, routeconfig

Parent component: App

```
@RouteConfig([
   {
     path: '...',
      name: 'Home',
     component: HomeCmp
   },
   {
    path: '/404',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: Error404Cmp
    },
   {
    path: '/*path',
    redirectTo: ['NotFound']
   }
  ])
```

Home component: Home

```
 @RouteConfig([
  {
     path: '',
     name: 'ItemsList',
     component: itemsListCmp,
     useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id/',
    name: 'ItemInfo',
    component: itemInfoCmp
   }
  ])
```

when I'm redirecting to ItemInfo path in url I have next:

---

http://localhost:9000/#//item/1

---

Why in url double slash "#//"? How can I fix it and got:
http://localhost:9000/#/item/1?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding a leading slash to the path of ItemInfo?  path: '/item/:id',

Comment: Which version of router you use here? Make sure you've got the latest

Comment: @Austin Yes, same thing..

Comment: @AngJobs thanks, on beta.17 version it works.